# Does Material Angular's side bar supports "lock in" once opening?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would know if there's any other UI library that supports this feature (Lock the side bar once opened). I know [this](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSidenav) would be useful but it's older so I'm still considering if Angular Material is still an option [the side bar's api](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/api) (for library consistency).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you're looking for the equivalent of the `mode` attribute on `MatDrawer`, which can be set to one of the following values as specified in the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview#changing-the-sidenavs-behavior):

- `over`: Sidenav floats over the primary content, which is covered by a backdrop
- `push`: Sidenav pushes the primary content out of its way, also covering it with a backdrop
- `side`: Sidenav appears side-by-side with the main content, shrinking the main content's width to make space for the sidenav.

You're probably looking for the `side` value.

Here's an example:

```html
<mat-sidenav mode="side">
  <!-- Contents of sidenav -->
</mat-sidenav>
```

And if you want to toggle the mode based on the device media, you could use the Angular CDK's [`BreakpointObserver`](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview) utility class.

(Note: The following code below was partially adapted from Angular Material's navigation schematic)

```js
export class YourComponent {
  isHandset$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset)
    .pipe(
      map(result => result.matches),
      shareReplay()
    );

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {}
}
```

And in your component's template:

```html
<mat-sidenav #drawer
  [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
  [opened]="(isHandset$ | async) === false">
  <!-- Contents of sidenav -->
</mat-sidenav>
```